# How can I make this question about c# exit codes more distinct from the proposed duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked this question yesterday: [Which exit codes can a .net program have, when Environment.Exit() is not used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536145/which-exit-codes-can-a-net-program-have-when-environment-exit-is-not-used)

It was soon mjölnir-closed as a duplicate of this question: [Getting ExitCode From Exception Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394877/getting-exitcode-from-exception-handler)

Unfortunately that question, to me, seems to be very much not a duplicate: My question asks which exit codes a .net program can have, when the exit code is not explicitely set. The other question asks how to explicitely set the exit code in one specific circumstance (which does not apply in my case).

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32395434/145999) in that question contains a sentence that *hints* at a partial answer to my question ("*if a program dies on an exception then its exit code is **normally** the same as the underlying exception error code*").
I think this was the reason this duplicate was chosen, since the author of that answer is the same one that closed my question. But I cannot extract a full answer to my question from this sentence alone.

I tried my best to reformulate my question to highlight the distinction between both questions, but apparently I failed to convince anyone else in the reopen-review queue, or anyone stumbling upon the question.

Is there anything i can to make this more clear?

Comment: normally == always until somebody finds a counter-example.  You can't get a warranty here.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that the duplicate is not obvious but I can see why Hans selected it.

Your question basically is, if I understand it correctly, about that one liner in Hans his answer.

I would add that line to your question and ask:

> If my program doesn't have an `Environment.Exit` call can I rely on the runtime to give me an exit code similar to what I would get if I call as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32395434/578411) by Hans Passant:
>
> ```
> Environment.Exit(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(e));
> ```

With that line the difference is clear and none of the answers on the dupe would fit. I went ahead and already casted a re-open vote on your question.

Comment: I agree. I un-mjölnired that question since the other question is certainly related, but I would't call it a duplicate.